# CRT WinAPI and variadic printf functions

Tags: unicode, printf, ascii, messagebox, crt

I am currently studying WinAPI GUI (Programming Windows 5th edition by Charles Petzold) and C(not C++) .I am trying and want to keep it as pure C as possible and maybe then jump to C++ or C#.
My problem relies on using the variadic `***printf***()` editions.

Project : I want to make a function that will be able to identify if I am using ASCII, UNICODE or another type of multibyte character set(MBCS) and then format the input accordingly and type the output in a MessageBox().

In the book that I am reading the author is using the source code below to make something similar :
SCRNSIZE.C

```
/*−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−
SCRNSIZE.C −− Displays screen size in a message box
(c) Charles Petzold, 1998
−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−*/
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int CDECL MessageBoxPrintf (TCHAR * szCaption, TCHAR * szFormat, ...)
{
TCHAR szBuffer [1024] ;
va_list pArgList ;
// The va_start macro (defined in STDARG.H) is usually equivalent to:
// pArgList = (char *) &szFormat + sizeof (szFormat) ;
va_start (pArgList, szFormat) ;
// The last argument to wvsprintf points to the arguments
_vsntprintf (szBuffer, sizeof (szBuffer) / sizeof (TCHAR),
szFormat, pArgList) ;
// The va_end macro just zeroes out pArgList for no good reason
va_end (pArgList) ;
return MessageBox (NULL, szBuffer, szCaption, 0) ;
}
int WINAPI WinMain (HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
PSTR szCmdLine, int iCmdShow)
{
int cxScreen, cyScreen ;
cxScreen = GetSystemMetrics (SM_CXSCREEN) ;
cyScreen = GetSystemMetrics (SM_CYSCREEN) ;
MessageBoxPrintf (TEXT ("ScrnSize"),
TEXT ("The screen is %i pixels wide by %i pixels high."),
cxScreen, cyScreen) ;
return 0 ;
}
```

The program displays the width and height of the video display in pixels by using information obtained
from the GetSystemMetrics function. GetSystemMetrics is a useful function for obtaining information
about the sizes of various objects in Windows.

From my understanding he is using TCHAR so that his function can handle UNICODE or ASCII.
TCHAR is defined as:

```
#ifdef UNICODE
typedef WCHAR TCHAR, * PTCHAR ;
typedef LPWSTR LPTCH, PTCH, PTSTR, LPTSTR ;
typedef LPCWSTR LPCTSTR ;
#else
typedef char TCHAR, * PTCHAR ;
typedef LPSTR LPTCH, PTCH, PTSTR, LPTSTR ;
typedef LPCSTR LPCTSTR ;
#endif
```

while `MessageBox()` is using the following trick to be able to handle either ASCII either UNICODE:

```
#ifdef UNICODE
#define MessageBox MessageBoxW
#else
#define MessageBox MessageBoxA
#endif
```

Before trying to code my project(i started but i had questions i couldn nott answer on my own) i would like to solve some puzzles i have not figured out yet.

1)How can he use `int` as a return type in `MessageBoxPrintf()` and be able to return a full C-object like `MessageBox()`?And in general what should my  return type be when i return full functions like MessageBox()?

2)The function the author is using is `_vsntprintf`.MSDN denies it exists but i found this in the source code:

```
#define _vsntprintf _vsnwprintf
int _vsnwprintf(wchar_t *_Buffer, size_t _BufferCount, const wchar_t *_Format, va_list _ArgList)
```

Also he is using two divisions with TCHAR to get the actual sizes of the buffer when we are
using UNICODE.

2)From your experience or preference is this version of printf still the best to use?
Because searching MSDN I found so many different variadic versions of `printf`.

3)Would you change anything in the code to make it more portable or more "correct"...I don't see any error handling and from what i have read it is always better to use `va_` macros which are black boxes so your code can be more portable.

I am sorry if some questions sound stupid but I am overwhelmed from this example.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) `MessageBox` is a function. He is returning the return value of the method `MessageBox`. Take a look at the documentation here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505(v=vs.85).aspx

2) Here's all the existing variations of vsnwprintf https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1kt27hek.aspx. Each type takes a different unity size (e.g.: byte, char, tchar, wchar, etc...).

The second argument of this methot requests the number of elements in the buffer. Given that `sizeof (szBuffer)` gives you the buffer size in `bytes` ( and not the quantity of `TCHAR`s inside the buffer), you have to divide it by the size of TCHAR (`sizeof(TCHAR)`). Thus,`sizeof (szBuffer) / sizeof (TCHAR)`.

3) I am a little bit lost on this one. Would mind improving on it?

Comment: 1)Thank you i get it now...5th time i write this comment...I dont know how to change line.2)We say the same thing ...from your experience do you have a preference in variadic printf function because many of them just do the same thing but maybe they have internally a difference in implementation and are more portable for example.3)Ideas and suggestions to improve the program like adding an error handling in a place that you know will likely fail or using something else instead of TCHAR...mostly ideas and suggestions.